# Typing a class instance whose parent class use Object.assign

Tags: typescript, types

I have the following:

```
type UserModel = {
  id: number;
  email: string;
};

export class ActiveRecord<T> {
  constructor(fields: T) {
    Object.assign(this, fields);
  }
}

class User extends ActiveRecord<UserModel> {}

const user = new User({ id: 1, email: "foo" });
```

This works completely in JS, but I can't have auto completition in TS on `user` since it is just of type `User` and not `User & UserModel`.

Is there any way I can fully type `user`?

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgzhATgWQPYBMIBsoF4oDeAUFFAJboBcUAdgK4C2ARkgNwlQQMCGZW1cYIjI0A5uwC+7IhAAeYVImBQAxlm5w4UAIIrgZAG4QAShBWL0AHgAqAPkIdzNQYjp7FACgBmZbOjjU1gCUDqSkAPJMAFZmwAB0GnBkojQewAAWZHAANFA+fnBB7KQSRKVEaomwCIicssAQNP46eoYmZhaW8EhomFj2BOVOglB0NXi0EADu1UgeBORUUACMuVy8-FAARF6oqFtQEkVERGNIcRRhAPRXqoqIsVAAUgDKUEx0yiLmiA96UNYXkA)

Comment: Class declarations require statically known keys in TypeScript; you can get behavior close to what you want, but you'll never be allowed to write `extends ActiveRecord<T>` if `ActiveRecord<T>` doesn't have statically known keys.   The best I can imagine looks like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wQ22GN).  Does that fully address your question? If so I could write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz is there any way to just accept objects of `UserModel`? On `user2` you are passing `birthday` in the "constructor"

Comment: Your `User` example is generic, so I made `User` generic too.  What was the point of `T extends UserModel` in your example code?  Assuming there is no point, you might want to [edit] it to `class User extends ActiveRecord<UserModel> {}`, and then you can do it [this way](https://tsplay.dev/m0YYGW).  Does that work better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript has a requirement that [`interface`s](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#interfaces), including the instance type of [`class`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html) declarations, must have *statically known keys*.  That means it is impossible to write a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) `class` declaration where the key names of class instances are themselves generic.  You can define the intended type of such a class constructor, but no `class` statement will result in a constructor of that type.

On the face of it that means what you're asking for is not possible, but depending on your use cases you can work around it.  One way to do it is to just [assert](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) that the `class` constructor is of the desired type:

```
const ActiveRecord = class {
  constructor(t: any) {
    Object.assign(this, t)
  }
} as { new <T extends object>(t: T): T }
```

Now there is an `ActiveRecord` class constructor and the compiler sees it as generic in exactly the intended way.  And you can even use it as a superclass as long as you *instantiate* `T` with a type with non-generic keys when you do so:

```
class User extends ActiveRecord<UserModel> {
  
} // okay

const user = new User({ id: 1, email: "foo" });
console.log(user.id.toFixed(1)); // okay, 1.0
```

The caveat about instantiation means that you can't do this:

```
class Bad<T> extends ActiveRecord<T> { } // error!
// Base constructor return type 'T' is not an object type 
// or intersection of object types with statically known members.
```

the keys of `T` are unknown at compile time, so the compiler complains.  You *can* make your subclasses generic as long as the type argument to `ActiveRecord` doesn't have any unknown *keys*:

```
class Good<T> extends ActiveRecord<{ b: T }> { } // okay
```

As long as you don't need *generic* class hierarchies ultimately derived from `ActiveRecord`, then this might be an acceptable approach.